# How to Split String with Containing Parentheses into multi-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following String:

```
"(X,Y,Z),(A,B,C),(R,S,T)"
```

I want to split this into a multi-dimensional array:

```
arr[0] = [x,y,z]
arr[1] = [a,b,c]
arr[2] = [r,s,t]
```

so that:

```
arr[0][1] = y,  arr[0][2] = z, etc.
```

I can do it by stripping the first and last parens, splitting on "),(" and then looping through that array and doing another split.   But I feel dirty, unpure, like a stripper (pun intended) in a backalley bar ... is there a cleaner way?

Maybe some LINQ to the rescue?

I'm using C#.

Comment: Do you know for sure it will be a two dimensional and non-jagged array?

Comment: Yep, always two dimensional, always the same number of elements in the second dimension (3)

Comment: Do you want a jagged array (as your code), or a 2D array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string data = "(X,Y,Z),(A,B,C),(R,S,T)";

string[][] stringses = data.Trim('(', ')')
    .Split(new[] {"),("}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(chunk => chunk.Split(','))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to make a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) (as your code shows) from this with string splitting and LINQ fairly easily:

```
string original = "(X,Y,Z),(A,B,C),(R,S,T)";

string[] groups = original.Trim('(',')')
                     .Split(new[] {"),("}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[][] results = groups.Select(g => g.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Regex is your friend. here is a simple snippet of code that does it for you.

```
var input = @"(X,Y,Z),(A,B,C),(R,S,T)";
var pattern = @"[A-Za-z,]+\b";

List<List<string>> twoDimentionList = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) 
{
    List<string> values = m.Value.Split(',').ToList<string>(); 
    twoDimentionList.Add(values)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can get your data with regular expressions

A reqular expression is: `(\(([A-Z]+)\,?\))+` this will give you x,y,z in groups.. and then just add them in your second dimension array :)